# UITableView does not respond to scrolling and touches

Tags: ipad, ios, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I've created a custom UIView, and inside that UIView, I add a UITableView like thus:

```
    treeView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, slider.frame.size.width, slider.frame.size.height - 80)];
    [treeView setDelegate:self];
    [treeView setDataSource:self];
    [self addSubview:treeView];
    [treeView release];
```

When the app loads, the table seems to load fine. However, when I try to scroll the table, it does not respond to the touches at all.

I also implement these delegate/data source methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is so?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

- Your custom view, or one of its superviews, has `userInteractionEnabled` set to NO.
- There is another view on top of your custom view, or on top of the table view within the custom view.
- The custom view that the table view is inside is smaller than the table view (with clipsToBounds=NO, a subview that extends beyond the bounds of its parent can be seen but not normally interacted with). Or the same for another view in the stack.
- The custom view (or one of its superviews) overrides `pointInside:withEvent:` or `hitTest:withEvent:` incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I had accidentally added my table to the bottom view.

Comment: thanks a lot, was working from 4 hrs,     The custom view that the table view is inside is smaller than the table view (with clipsToBounds=NO, a subview that extends beyond the bounds of its parent can be seen but not normally interacted with). Or the same for another view in the stack.

Comment: The third one was causing it for me. I had accentually initialized a UIView with just `init` instead of `initWithFrame:`, so it was smaller than the UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure userInteractionEnabled is YES on the view(s) that need to receive touch events. Also try calling becomeFirstResponder on the view as well and call resignFirstResponder when you're done. Sorry I don't have more detail but it's been a while since I did this. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another reason why it can happen...

The UITableView is a child of another view where the frame is smaller than the table view. It doesn't seem make much sense but it can happen! I had a case ware the parent of the tableview  had a width=0.

Which of course caused pointInside:withEvent: or hitTest:withEvent: to return NO!

Answer (score 0):

For me, The reason why my TabView was not responding is because of the transform animation. I was animating my Table view using 
`view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.5,0.5,0);`
which is 3D transformation property. I found out that by using 2D transformation instead `toVC.view.layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);` 
Then my table view becomes responding to my touches and scrolling.
I am not sure exactly what is the root cause but this is my observation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someOne will need this answer:

> make your view add to cell directly, not to `cell.content`

This work for me, when not use cell in table, but normal view.
It seems touches will not forward to contentView in this moment.